# Browser perform a request insted of show data uri

Tags: apache, browser, cross-browser, data-uri

My Apache registered a data URI in access log.

```
/data:image/png%3bbase64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAMAAACeL25MAAAABlBMVEUzlME6qNuT3ZmEAAAAE0lEQVQI12NgZGRkYABiMAQzGQEAjAANk73rMwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Apparently some browser did not understand the data URI and performed a request.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use some feature detector on client side (for example, [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)). And then check whether this feature is supported on document load. If it is not - replace all such urls with, for example, a path to a blank image.

In addition you could just block data uris in you firewall or on your front-end server.